# Weekly Writer's Chat 2013

Tags: discussion, chat

Weekly Writer's Chat is back on a regular meeting schedule after a hiatus.  We meet Tuesdays in The Overlook Hotel starting at 1700 UTC (1pm EDT) and generally wrap up anywhere from 2pm to 4pm Eastern, depending on how much people feel like chatting.

### What we do in chat:

We have informal writing exercises, and a 10-minute timed writing on a surprise topic.

Chatters are free to participate or not, and to ask for critique or not. **All are welcome to come, read, and discuss**; completing the exercise is not required.

### How to share your writing with the group:

Chatters are encouraged to post their exercises on their blog or other website, or by using Pastebin or Google docs, or by pretty much any method that allows the chatter to share a link in chat.

Chatters who post on their blogs may optionally include the following site-promotional boilerplate, provided to us by Mr. Shiny and New:

> This blog post is a writing exercise from writers.stackexchange.com.
>   Visit the Writers chat room every Tuesday for new writing exercises.
>   This week's exercise: [the text of the exercise]

### About the writing exercises:

- The criteria for the weekly exercises are posted and pinned in the chat room.
- Please share only a link to avoid cluttering the room with criss-crossing text walls.

The exercises are selected based on what chatters want to practice for writing techniques.

### How the 10-minute timed write works:

- The topic will be announced in chat when everyone is ready.
- Volunteers may give a topic if they want to. Please coordinate with the host if you want to suggest the timed writing topic or you may suggest a topic in an answer to this question.
- After ten minutes, the host will declare that time is up.
- Please use the same sharing method as the weekly exercises (paste a link).

The purpose of the timed exercise is to help you *just write*, without worrying about editing or revising or even making sense.

All exercises are for fun. We want you to have a good time writing and talking about writing, as well as have an excuse to sit and write at least once a week. If you have suggestions for writing exercises, feel free to post them here, or better yet, come to chat and discuss them! See you there.

Comment: I'm glad to see this coming back!  (I can't actually participate as most blogs, Google docs, and just about anything else useful for posting is blocked from work, but I enjoy reading these after the fact.)